# How to create duration dummies for event occurrence?

Tags: r

I have a panel data set and I would like to implement a BTSCS as a proportional hazards model and crate binary variables, where k_t are duration dummies indicating the number of periods since the last event. For example:

```
pid Conservatism year   Happiness Income       Unemployment   Inflation  k1  k2 k3  k4  k5

1     1         1990     1        1000          10             2           1   0  0  0  0
1     0         1991     1        2000           5             4           1   0  0  0  0
1     0         1992     2        3000           6             4           0   1  0  0  0
1     1         1993     3        1000           7             5           0   0  1  0  0
1     0         1994     3        1000           7             5           1   0  0  0  0
```

Comment: My guess is that it will be the `Happiness` column.  Is it right?

Comment: Conservatism is Y :)

Comment: If that is the case, why do you have `k1` with first two rows as 1.  Also, based on your previous example, it seems logical to me that the values start from 1:N rather than 1 and a bunch of 0's.

Comment: I mean we have to start somewhere. This is due to the limitation of the example: http://faculty.washington.edu/cadolph/pan/topic10.pw.pdf on page 14...is my example.

Comment: In the pdf, the duration column starts from `1` following a sequence.  It seems easy to find those variable. The time column is just unique values ie. `nrow(df)==length(unique(df$time))` and `y` has a lot of 0's.

Comment: Sorry, I am assuming that you already have a `duration` or similar column in the dataset in addition to the `y` column in the pdf.

Comment: My question was quite confusing. I just realized that. Im very sorry. But there was no such variable in my data...

Comment: Please show an example that mimics the data.  Also, it may be better to have as a new post as more eyes will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear about the `k4` to `k7`.  One way to create `k1` to `k3` would be:

```
 nm1 <- paste0('k', 1:3)
 df[nm1] <- Map(`==`, list(df$duration), unique(df$duration))
 df[nm1] <- df[nm1]*1
 df
 #  id y year duration k1 k2 k3
 #1  1 1 1990        1  1  0  0
 #2  1 0 1991        1  1  0  0
 #3  1 0 1992        2  0  1  0
 #4  1 0 1993        3  0  0  1
 #5  1 1 1994        1  1  0  0
 #6  1 0 1995        2  0  1  0
 #7  1 1 1996        1  1  0  0
 #8  2 1 1990        1  1  0  0
 #9  2 0 1991        1  1  0  0
```

#### Update

Another option would be to use `model.matrix`

```
 df[nm1] <- model.matrix(~0+factor(duration), df)
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), y = c(1L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1990L, 1991L), duration = c(1L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "y", "year", "duration"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: yes that I was looking for. Thank you!! How would you set up your duration variable for large N? I suppose based on that you just have to use the lenght command to get the K:K_i...

Comment: @Googme Sorry, I didn't quite understand the question.  For large `N`, means if there are a lot of  values for the `unique(duration)`, right?.  In that case, `nm1 <- paste0('k', seq_along(unique(df$duration)))`

Comment: I´m sorry for my expression. I mean you set k (k:k3) manually. And k depends on duration variable. If my duration variable would be unknown(unkown in terms that i just cant count each observation to determine duration in large data sets) and i had to determine it how should I do that...but I think you just gave the answer :)

Comment: @Googme A better option would be to use `model.matrix` i.e `model.matrix(~0+factor(duration), df)`

Comment: @ akrun...the model.matrix seems a very usefull command. However As I mentioned above. How do you determine "duration" variable in respect to Y? You set it up manuelly.

Comment: @Googme I set it up after viewing the `dataset`.  In the example you showed, it may be difficult to find `duration` variable without looking at the data because the variable is `numeric` and there might be other `numeric` variables in your dataset.  Is there any limitation in looking at the dataset?

Comment: the problem is that the "duration" variable is required to set up the whole process. but that is the most important aspect.given the upper data set without "duration". How do you determine the duration variable? I mean the example data set approaches my real one. but  i cant implement your suggestions because i struggle to determine "duration"

Comment: @Googme I couldn't understand why it is difficult to determine the variable.  How many columns do you have?

Comment: I just uploaded the structure above. I mean that is a panel with lot of persons(pid). I mean your suggestions makes sense but if your have more than 1000000 rows that you cant just count each lenght of occurances manually("duration").

Comment: @Googme I will look at the structure.